# In salesforce DX how do I create a scratch org with a community

Tags: community, salesforcedx

To clarify I can create a scratch org where I can manually add a community I have setup the OrgPreference.settings and the features in project-scratch-def.json correctly.
The problem is when I create a community pull back the metadata and try to create another scratch org with the updated metadata I get the following:

```
force-app\main\default\portals\Customer Portal.portal-meta.xml  Not available for deploy for this organization
force-app\main\default\networks\Test.network-meta.xml           Not available for deploy for this organization
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is in those files, but my guess would be that they contain e.g. the domain name and that can't be moved between orgs. We ended up doing quite a lot of scripting so we can automatically create a fully configured community org.

Comment: I don't see a reference to domain in them, but I'm starting to think its not possible.  Really I just want a test community so that I can test partner users but partner users need a profile associated with a community.

Comment: can you post your 2nd scratch org `project-scratch-def.json` file settings

Comment: `{
    "orgName": "Demo Company",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": ["Communities"]
}`

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly activate the community on the scratch org definition file to be able to deploy a community. Check the `communitiesSettings` attribute below:

```
{
   "orgName": "Demo Company",
   "edition": "Enterprise",
   "features": ["Communities"],
   "settings": {
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
        }
    }
}
```